# Using UIWebView to create hyperlinks in UITableView Footer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, hyperlink

I am trying to create a UIWebView in UITableView footer. The table is grouped. Actually I am trying to create a hyperlink using UIWebView. For example there should be some text like

**Hey folks Contact me**

Contact me should be a hyperlink and I want to place this text in UITableView footer. I am unable to figure out how to do it..please guide me guys..if possible please post some sample code or please give me a link for the tutorial..I didn't use IB here to create the webview..I just declared webview in .h file

This is the code I wrote in viewForFooterInSection method

```
CGRect webFrame = CGRectMake(20,500,buttonView.frame.size.width,buttonView.frame.size.height);  
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];  
        webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  
        [self.view addSubview:webView];  
        NSString *html = @"<html><head></head><body>Hey Folks Contact Us</br></body></html>";  
        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];
```

Comment: Do you want to put it as a view in section or in table? If in table, you should use viewForFooterInTable.

Comment: Yup I want to use it as a view in table..even if there are no sections present the webview with hyperlink should be displayed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully relevant: [UIButton in UITableView Footer](http://blog.blackwhale.at/?p=104)

They are creating a button at the UITableView footer with a UIView so maybe you can implement the same using your UIWebView instead of the UIButton.

Comment: thanks for the reply Kennzo..I created buttons for another purpose and its working fine..I am unable to use UIWebView as I think I am doing some mistake in the above code..

Comment: Unfortunately the link is now dead. That's why you should always copy at least some of the content from the source rather than just linking to an external page when answering.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a custom footer to a table you have a property - tableFooterView.
you need to assign the webView you're creating to this property.

In your table view controller's viewDidLoad method do the following:

```
if (self.tableView.tableFooterView == nil) {
            // Create your webView (move here your code)
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = yourWebView;
}
```

This works for me, I create my view from nib file.